# Huge persisting memory allocation with go-ethereum `bind.NewTransactor()`?

Tags: go, memory, cryptography, ethereum, go-ethereum

I am developing a REST service that interacts with a private Ethereum blockhain network. First, I used Java with the Web3j library and Jersey. Everything worked as expected but a single instance of the service (not the geth client) **was taking up to 500MB of RAM!** As I need several instances (~40) running at the same time for simulation purpose, I wanted something lighter.

Thus I switched to Go (32-bit version, Windows 10) and the original go-ethereum package. However, I was very surprised to find out that the memory consumption of the program **rises up to ~250MB** as soon as I call and store the result of `bind.NewTransactor()`, which returns a `*TransactOpts`. I took a look at the sources but I could not explain such behavior.

Is that normal (and if yes, why?) or am I missing something?

Here is my code:

```
import (
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind"
    "strings"
)

const WALLET_PATH string = "path/to/json/wallet"

func main() {

    data, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(WALLET_PATH)
    // up to this point, the program only takes a few MBs of RAM 

    auth, _ := bind.NewTransactor(strings.NewReader(string(data)), "mypassphrase")
    // and here the allocated memory rises up to ~270MB
    _ = auth
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9833/is-it-possible-to-decrease-ram-usage-of-go-ethereumgeth ?

Comment: @Ullaakut Thanks for the link. However, as I said, I am not talking about the geth node, I am just talking about running the code I posted. Plus, I am not trying to send any transactions so far. Actually, the ethclient connection part of the code above can be removed and still the memory consumption is very high...

Comment: Try [memory profiling](https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs) it.

Comment: Geth is a fairly large program, and the internal code is quite interlinked. Using even a subset of geth can require running a lot of code.

Comment: @RaghavSood Indeed. Please have a look at my edited question and my answer, you'll see that I am only dealing with cryptographic implementation issues so I do not think that Geth's size is involved howsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, I did not *really* found the answer to my question, but as I did find a workaround I'll share it anyway.

### Memory profiling

As @MichaelHampton suggested, I memory profiled my program. `top 10` command revealed the following:

```
(pprof) top 10
Showing nodes accounting for 256MB, 99.88% of 256.30MB total
Dropped 15 nodes (cum <= 1.28MB)
    flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
    256MB 99.88% 99.88%      256MB 99.88%  github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/scrypt.Key
        0     0% 99.88%      256MB 99.88%  github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind.NewTransactor
        0     0% 99.88%      256MB 99.88%  github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/keystore.DecryptKey
        0     0% 99.88%      256MB 99.88%  github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/keystore.decryptKeyV3
        0     0% 99.88%      256MB 99.88%  github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/keystore.getKDFKey
        0     0% 99.88%   256.01MB 99.88%  main.main
        0     0% 99.88%   256.30MB   100%  runtime.main
```

As you can see, the memory consumption comes from the `Key` function in package `scrypt`, which is called indirectly by `bind.NewTransactor(...)`. From the doc:

> Key derives a key from the password, salt, and cost parameters, returning a byte slice of length keyLen that can be used as cryptographic key.

In particular, this corresponds to how a private key is generated from a JSON wallet file. Indeed, the function itself allocates a lot of memory for cryptographic computations. What I do not understand though is why this huge memory allocation **seems to persist once the key has been generated** (the persistence is observed when I start the server with `log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))` just after).

### Workaround

To confirm my suspicion, I used another way to generate my `*TransactOpts`, which consists in getting the key directly form its hexadecimal representation instead of generating it from a wallet file:

```
func main() {
    privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA("myKeyInHex")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    auth := bind.NewKeyedTransactor(privateKey)

    _ = auth
}
```

Although `bind.NewTransactor` and `bind.NewKeyedTransactor` return exactly the same object (the only difference being how the key was generated), using `bind.NewTransactor` results in a 256MB **persisting** memory allocation, instead of a few KB for `bind.NewKeyedTransactor` as shown below:

```
(pprof) top 10
Showing nodes accounting for 11.04kB, 100% of 11.04kB total
Showing top 10 nodes out of 19
    flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
  6.83kB 61.90% 61.90%     6.83kB 61.90%  time.initLocalFromTZI
  4.21kB 38.10%   100%     4.21kB 38.10%  github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/sha3.(*state).clone (inline)
       0     0%   100%     4.21kB 38.10%  github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind.NewKeyedTransactor
       0     0%   100%     4.21kB 38.10%  github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto.Keccak256
       0     0%   100%     4.21kB 38.10%  github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto.PubkeyToAddress
       0     0%   100%     4.21kB 38.10%  github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/sha3.(*state).Sum
       0     0%   100%     6.83kB 61.90%  github.com/pkg/profile.Start
       0     0%   100%     6.83kB 61.90%  github.com/pkg/profile.Start.func2
       0     0%   100%     6.83kB 61.90%  log.(*Logger).Output
       0     0%   100%     6.83kB 61.90%  log.(*Logger).formatHeader
```

Thus, for my simulation I will generate my private keys from my JSON wallets and store them in text files upstream, and then use `bind.NewKeyedTransactor(...)`. I know this is not safe howsoever but for my simulation purpose it will be sufficient.

However, I'm pretty sure `bind.NewTransactor` does not have the expected behavior concerning memory consumption, so I am going to open an [issue on the `go-ethereum` repository](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17411).